# Mean Value and what it says about behavior on functions on an interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f :\mathbb {R} \to\mathbb {R}$ and on some interval $(a, b)$ I know the mean value is $-1$. Not being given very much about $f $, is there anything I can infer about the number of local extrema on this interval? Or the number of inflection points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The mean value tells you absolutely nothing about this type of info.

Think about any function you can imagine. (With any number of local extrema and inflection points.) Call it $f$.

If it is integrable on $(a,b)$, then it has a mean value on that interval. If you move the function up or down, you change the mean value continuously, without altering any of the features like local extrema or inflection points. If you move it the right direction/amount, the mean value will become $-1$. (Regardless of what the function looks like.)